# webview implementation using MvvmCross android native XAMARIN

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-webview, mvvmcross

We are using mvvmcross for Xamarin android native but unable to use webview to render html page, please help if anyone tried ...regular xamarin android can do but since we use mvvmcross then that regular won't work

We tried using mvvmcross XAMRIN also added plugin https://nuget.info/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.WebBrowser/8.0.2 but nothing works

Comment: it won't work for us as we uses MVVMCross framework, thanks

Comment: <android.webkit.WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
         local:MvxBind="TextFormatted TestHtml"/>   we want something this to work out and we should be able to set dynamic content to it

Comment: Well, you can check [official doc about MVVMCROSS](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/). Wish it can help you.

Comment: Did you send documentation link for MVVMcross or we are missing something? as we already run through documentation, don't find there any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Did it from View because below `LoadDataWithBaseURL()` function is not supported/working in ViewModel
i have added below code in View.

```
WebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, Html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

In design

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/ReceiptWebView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

It will load HTMl with Table.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. I've tested with MvvmCross 8.0.2. This code is slightly modified [from Google](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/739e304a-7ec4-47c6-b0e9-59ef4e966283/how-to-bind-to-webview-in-mvvmcross?forum=xamarincrossplatform)

You could also probably just use the MvvmCross Web Browser plugin by first saving your HTML to a file then using a "file://..." URI.

```cs
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Webkit;
using System;

namespace MyApp.Droid.Ui.Controls
{
    [Register("myapp.droid.ui.controls.MvxWebView")]
    public class MvxWebView : WebView
    {
        private string _text;

        [Preserve(Conditional = true)]
        public MvxWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        [Preserve(Conditional = true)]
        public string Text
        {
            get
            { 
                return _text;
            }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    return;
                }

                _text = value;

                LoadData(_text, "text/html", "utf-8");
                UpdatedHtmlContent();
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler HtmlContentChanged;

        private void UpdatedHtmlContent()
        {
            HtmlContentChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```xml
    <myapp.droid.ui.controls.MvxWebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:MvxBind='Text MyHtml' />
```

...and in your ViewModel:

```cs
public string MyHtml
{
    get => _myHtml;
    set => SetProperty(ref _myHtml, value);
}

MyHtml = "<html><p>Hello, World!</p></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a solution to fix the non-working WebView; but if indeed this is an outstanding compatibility issue, maybe looking into [MvvmsCross' WebBrowser](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/webbrowser) plugin might be a suitable workaround fir your application.

Comment: it open up that URL but in our case we have to render html content like webview, this we already tried no luck